# AND vs OR in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm coming back to T-SQL after a few years away. I'm trying to do a SQL query like the following, but it seems like the OR clause is making it ignore the AND.

Is there a way to get the objects whose `syscolumns.name` contains 'sp' or 'tbl' but whose XTYPE is NOT P?

I've tried using parentheses, but SQL Server doesn't seem to like them.

```
use master

SELECT 
    c.name AS columnname, o.name AS tablename, o.xtype
FROM 
    syscolumns c 
JOIN 
    sysobjects o ON c.id = o.id
WHERE 
    UPPER(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%sp%') 
    OR UPPER(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%tbl%') 
    AND o.xtype NOT LIKE ('P%')
ORDER BY 
    tablename DESC
```

Comment: SQL Server LOVES parenthesis.   What did you try that it didn't like?

Comment: Your query will do this `upper(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%sp%') 
OR (upper(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%tbl%') 
AND o.xtype NOT LIKE ('P%'))`

Comment: Also, by now, you should check out the `sys` catalog schema, and use views like `sys.columns` and `sys.tables` etc. - not the old, legacy `sysobjects` or `syscolumns` - those are deprecated

Answer (score 3):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. You'll need to add parenthesis to compute `OR` first, as in:

```
SELECT c.name AS columnname, o.name AS tablename, o.xtype
FROM syscolumns c 
JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id = o.id
WHERE 
( -- added parenthesis
upper(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%sp%') 
OR upper(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%tbl%') 
) -- added parenthesis
AND o.xtype NOT LIKE ('P%')
ORDER BY tablename desc
```

Answer (score 1):

this works, I just added parenthesis to the where clause.

```
use master
SELECT c.name AS columnname, o.name AS tablename, o.xtype
FROM syscolumns c 
JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id = o.id
WHERE 
(upper(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%sp%') OR upper(c.name) LIKE UPPER('%tbl%') )
AND o.xtype NOT LIKE ('P%')
ORDER BY tablename desc
```